# Solving equation consisting of fractional part and greatest integer functions

Tags: calculus, functions

I don't understand how to go about solving $$[x]^2 = x+2\{x\}$$
where [.] and {.} denote the greatest integer and the fractional part function, respectively. I tried converting the entire equation in terms of the fractional part function, but couldn't figure out where to go from there. Also, can it be solved graphically?

Comment: "greatest integer"?  Is that the floor function ($[x] \le x < [x]+1$) as I assumed.  Or the ceiling function $[x]-1 < x \le [x]$) as user assumed?

Comment: @fleablood I thnk it is indeed the floor function!

Answer (score 3):

Note $[x]^2 = x +2\{x\} = [x]+3\{x\}$

So $[x]^2 - [x] =[x]([x]-1) = 3\{x\}$

So we have a few observations:

$[x]([x]-1)=k$ is an integer.

$0 \le 3\{x\} < 3$ so $k = 0,1,2$.

And $\{x\} = \frac k3$.

If $k = 0$ then $\{x\} = 0$ and either $[x]=0$ or $[x]=1$ so $x = 0$ or $x =1$.

If $k= 1$ then $[x]([x]-1) = 1$ has no solutions (the only factorisation of $1$ is $1^2$ or $(-1)^2$ but $[x] \ne [x]-1$.

If $k=2$ then either $[x]=2, [x]-1=1$ or $[x]=-1; [x]-1= -2$. so $x=2\frac 23$ or $x=-\frac 13$.

So $x= 0, 1, -\frac 13, 2\frac 23$

Comment: What do  you mean by $2\frac 23$?

Comment: $2\frac 23 = 2 + \frac 23 = \frac 83$.  Standard notation, no?

Comment: $-1/3$ is not a solution

Comment: Why not?  $[-\frac 13] = -1$ and $\{-\frac 13\} = \frac 23$ and $(-1)^2 = -\frac 13 + 2*\frac 23$.  'tis a solution.

Comment: I think I'm assuming a uncorrect definition for these functions. I revise that. Thanks

Comment: Floor function  (if indeed it is a floor function) is usually defined by the unique integer $n$ so that $n \le x < n+1$ and the fractional part is $x - \lfloor x \rfloor$.  If this is the correct definition, then for negative numbers are bit confusing as $\lfloor x \rfloor \ne -\lfloor |x| \rfloor$ and $\{x\}$ (which must be between $0$ inclusive and $1$ exclusive) not equal to either $\{|x|\}$ or $-\{|x|\}$.  If $x$ is not an integer then  $\lfloor x \rfloor = -\lceil |x| \rceil$ and $\{x\} = 1- \{|x|\}$.

Comment: BTW.... Isn't floor and ceiling function in MathJax the *worst*?!

Comment: Thanks! Now I've clarified and I obtain the same results. Bye