# Finding solutions to $[x]^2 + 2[x]-3x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

[Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3442337/solving-equation-consisting-of-fractional-part-and-greatest-integer-functions), I was attempting the question in an alternative way I wrote $ \{ x \} = x-[x]$, then after subbing that into the equation I got the following quadratic :

$$ [x]^2 + 2[x]-3x=0$$
I rearrange this as:

$$ [x]^2 + 2 [x]  = 3x$$

Adding one:

$$ ( [x] +1)^2 = 3x+1$$

Or,

$$ [x] + 1 = \pm \sqrt{3x+1}$$

Now, I use property to take in $1$ to the box function:

$$ [1+x] = \pm \sqrt{3x+1}$$

Now , I substitute $ x+1 = u$, this leads to:

$$ [u] = \pm \sqrt{3u-2}$$

The bound on $u$ is given as $ u \geq \frac23$, it is clear that the $ [u]= - \sqrt{3u-2}$ has no solutions because left side is always positive for $u \geq \frac23$ , hence can't be equal to negative number of RHS. This leads to a single inequality:

$$ [u] = \sqrt{3u-2}$$

This leads for checking when $3u-2$ is perfect square:

$$ 3u-2 = 0$$

$$ 3u-2=1 \implies u=1$$
$$ 3u -2 = 4 \implies u=2$$
$$ 3u-2 =9 \implies u= \frac{11}{2}$$

Seems like there are no solutions for $ u >2$ , so how do I proof that this is the case?

Comment: I am not sure what needs to be proved? You showed there are no solutions for $u>2 \iff x > 1$

Comment: How did I show that there are no solutions if u>2? It @gt6989b, if I keep checking higher number it doesn't come but how do I give a reason to prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[u] = \sqrt{3u - 2}$ has no solution if $\sqrt{3u-2} < u-1$ since $[u] > u-1$.

This is equivalent to $3u-2 < u^2-2u+1$, or $u^2-5u+3 = (u-2.5)^2 - 3.25 > 0$

Hence there is no solution for $u$ if $u > \sqrt{3.25} + 2.5 \approx 4.30278$.

Comment: How did you get the inequality $[u]>u-1$

Comment: By definition $[u]$ is the largest integer not exceeding $u$. So $[u]+1 > u$.

Comment: Amazing idea, thank you

Answer (score 5):

Using $\{x\}$ is advantageous. The original equation transforms to
$$[x]^2-[x]=3\{ x\}$$

LHS is an integer $\Rightarrow$ $\{x\}=0,1/3,2/3$.
So $x$ is $n$ or $n+1/3$ or $n+2/3$ for some integer $n$.

Substituting these in original equation gives
$$n^2-n=0,1,2$$

which can be easily solved. Now there is no need to check anything. Only correct solutions will be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

$\left[{x}\right]^{\mathrm{2}} +\mathrm{2}\left[{x}\right]−\mathrm{3}{x}=\mathrm{0} \\ $
$\left[{x}\right]^{\mathrm{2}} −\left[{x}\right]−\mathrm{3}\left\{{x}\right\}=\mathrm{0} \\ $
$\left[{x}\right]=\frac{\mathrm{1}\pm\sqrt{\mathrm{1}+\mathrm{12}\left\{{x}\right\}}}{\mathrm{2}}\:\in\left\{-\mathrm{1},\mathrm{0},\mathrm{1},\mathrm{2}\right\} \\ $
${x}=\frac{\left(\left[{x}\right]+\mathrm{1}\right)^{\mathrm{2}} −\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{3}}\in\left\{\frac{-\mathrm{1}}{\mathrm{3}},\mathrm{0},\mathrm{1},\frac{\mathrm{8}}{\mathrm{3}}\right\} \\ $